# My form onSubmit = "" syntax is a little hazy

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So for some reason, when I click on the submit button, it does not seem to be referring to my validate() function. Maybe it just isn't showing up on my console, but something is definitley wrong with my submit button/the validate function. I have looked up the correct onSubmit syntax and my validate() function seems to be functional, but still nothing happens when I click the submit button. All suggestions are very welcome.

html5 code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onSubmit="return validate()">
        First name: <input id = "firstName" type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br/> 
        Last name: <input id = "lastName" type="text" name="lastname" value="last name"><br/> 
        <div class = "text"><textarea>(Optional Bio)</textarea>
        <p></p> <input type="radio" id = "python">Master Race Python User
        <p></p> <input type="radio" id = "ruby">Imperial Ruby Scum
        </div>

        <div class = "languages">
        <h3>Languages Known</h3>
        <input type="checkbox">Python 
        <input type="checkbox">Ruby
        <input type="checkbox">html
        <input type="checkbox">CSS
        <input type="checkbox">Javascript
        <input type="checkbox">jQuery
        <input type="checkbox">Other
        <input type="checkbox" checked>Filthy casual
        <p><input type ="submit"></p>
        </div>


        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    background-color:#00ffff;
    border:solid black;
    border-radius:3%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px
}
.languages {
    background-color:#FFFF33;
    border:solid black;
    border-radius:15%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#check {
    background-color:#ABCDEF;
    border:solid black;
    width:50px;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#response {
    background-color:#FEDCBA;
}
```

javascript/jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function checkFirstname() {
    var username=$("#firstName").val();
    var namePat = /^[a-z]{2,16}$/i;
    var nameTest = namePat.test(username);

    if(!nameTest) {
        alert("First name may only contain letters and numbers, and must be 2-16 characters in length.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
    function checkLastname() {
    var username=$("#firstName").val();
    var namePat = /^[a-z]{2,16}$/i;
    var nameTest = namePat.test(username);

    if(!nameTest) {
        alert("Last name may only contain letters, and must be 2-16 characters in length.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function checkSide() {
    var python = document.getElementById("python").checked;
    var ruby = document.getElementById("ruby").checked;

    if(!python && !ruby) {
        alert("Please select a side");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function validate() {
    if(checkFirstname() === false) {
        return false;
    }
    if(checkLastName() ===  false) {
        return false; 
    }
    if(checkSide() === false) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

})
```

Comment: Please create a *minimal* test-case and include *error* messages and/or other symptoms. In this case, it will be an *error* because there is no `window.checkSide` due to it being defined within IIFE!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validate function is not being called because it is not in the scope of the document. Instead, it is scoped inside of an anonymous function being used as a callback for jQuery's document.ready shortcut. In order to have this function called, it needs to be exposed to the global scope of the page. A simple way to do this is to change the definition like this:

```
window.validate = function() {
  if(checkFirstname() === false) {
    return false;
  }
  if(checkLastName() ===  false) {
    return false; 
  }
  if(checkSide() === false) {
    return false;
  }
 return true;
};
```

A more functional way would probably be to simply include this in your jQuery document.ready shortcut and remove the inline code on your element ( `"onSubmit=validate()"` ).

```
$(function(){
 //other code

 $("form")[0].onsubmit = function(){
  return validate();
 }
});
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! I put the 

 "$("form")[0].onsubmit = function(){
  return validate();
 }"       Bit of code in and everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `validate` is defined *inside* the function scope created be `$document.ready(function ..)` and thus the function is *not* bound to `window.validate`. That particular `validate` is only visible from code *within* the same function scope and is thus *not* in scope in the "onsubmit" code<sup>1</sup> (which does not run in the same context).

Either ..

1. Bind the function to `window.validate` - e.g. `window.validate = function () { .. }`, ick! While this will work, it's sort of messy and pollutes `window`. Or;
2. Attach the event dynamically - e.g. [`.select`](http://api.jquery.com/select/), *not* an inline event - in which case the function-object can be resolved with the given name. This is generally a cleaner option and my recommendation.

---

<sup>1</sup> Make sure to include relevant (console) error messages in the future questions - this would result in "ReferenceError: validate is not defined" or similar.